# Cannot connect to mysql server in an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I have a problem in connecting to my MySQL server running on an EC2 Ubuntu instance.

In the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`,

- I've set the `port=3306`
- I've set the`bind-address=0.0.0.0`.
- Commented `skip-external-locking`

`netstat -an | grep 3306` returns

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I allowed the connections using `sudo ufw allow 3306`

Still Iam getting the error as below. (I have added the db.apim.com to `/etc/hosts` )

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db.apim.com' (110)
```

Note  : I followed everything in this [blog](https://linuxize.com/post/mysql-remote-access/)

Comment: 110 is a timeout. How have you added the record to your `hosts`?

Comment: Have you whitelisted the traffic to port in AWS Security Group attached to your VM?

Comment: Like this `34.201.40.105        db.apim.com`. 
I can successfully ssh to `db.apim.com` without any issues

Comment: @GobindDeepSingh    By default 0.0.0.0/0 is added as a inbound traffic rule. Then it should access from all IPs right ?

Comment: Is this corresponding to the correct port no. 3306?

Comment: Are you accessing the db from remote or local? IF from remote, have you tried with the ip instead of the domain name? have you allowed 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports or just ssh?

Comment: @Riz 0.0.0.0/0  has been allowed for ssh only and now i allowed for TCP/All Traffic and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by adding a suitable inbound traffic rule.
By adding `Type : TCP` and `Source: 0.0.0.0/0` as a new inbound traffic rule this issue resolved [1].

Thanks @GobindDeepSingh for pointing this out.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html